# how to download the div tag description in image format using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[update with my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kezx.png)

```js
$(function() {

  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.1.135/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.uriit.ru/jsPDF/libs/adler32cs.js/adler32cs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library/BlobBuilder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pdf.js"></script>


<div id="target">
  <div id="content">
    <h3>Hello, this is mathit app</h3>
    <a class="upload">Upload to Formulas</a>
    <h2>
            This is <b>10th Std Notes</b> <span style="color: red"></span>
        </h2>
    <p>Study about The polynomial of degree two is called quadratic polynomial and equation corresponding to a quadratic polynomial P(x) is called a quadratic equation in variable x. Thus, P(x) = ax2 + bx + c =0, R is known as the standard form of quadratic
      equation. There are two types of quadratic equation. (i) Complete quadratic equation : The equation ax2 + bx + c =0 where a,b,c is not equal to 0. (ii) Pure quadratic equation : An equation in the form of ax2 = 0, a is not equal to 0, b,c is equal
      to 0.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

How to download the div tag details and save have png image. I have some code in download the double time download in pdf  i want to download the one in pdf and another one in png image how to change the code please help me for example user click the button to down load the pdf and png image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with the help of [HTML2Canvas jquery file](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases) and HTML5 download attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var element = $("#html-content-holder"); // global variable
  var getCanvas; // global variable
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

      getCanvas = canvas;
    }
  });
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $("#cmd").on('click', function() {
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#cmd").attr("download", "Sample_Pic.png").attr("href", newData);

    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });


});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q9no9tdv/)

Comment: Happy to know my answer was helpful.

Comment: How to link the file in html2canvas and whish version are suitable please help me@Dil85

Comment: @PrasanthKlr  I am used jquery file with version 2.1.1. File that can be used in external source of jsfiddle.

Comment: what is shot.js?that was not mentioned question.Could please check the supporting jquery version shot.js

Comment: its my js link file its above javascript not a library file.

Comment: Maybe you are calling the ready function before the JQuery Javascript is included or Check the order you're including your scripts jquery file first.